# How to add timestamp in python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I want to set timestamp as I wnat. But
There was an error in doing it this way like this

```
dir.set({
        u'done':False,
        u'from':datetime.date(2022, 10, 20)
    })
```

```
('Cannot convert to a Firestore Value', datetime.date(2022, 10, 20), 'Invalid type', <class 'datetime.date'>)
```

Comment: There is nothing in the timestamp snippet

Comment: Where is the error? Please edit your post

Comment: As a side note, you are using "u" strngs (e.g., `u'done'`) which were needed in python 2 but not in python 3. Internet examples using u strings are usually out of date.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that Firestore does not accept the python Datetime object as a type.

Instead, cast your datetime object to a string before sending it over and you should be good.

Something like this should work

```
dir.set({
        'done':False,
        'from':datetime.date(2022, 10, 20).strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
    })
```

Comment: But in this way, It is not saved in timestamp format, but as a string

Comment: Why is that a problem? But, if you're okay with using the server time (i.e. not a pre-set time), you could use 'from': firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP. Regardless, python's date time object is an 'Invalid type' per the error message.

Comment: 'from':firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP(2022/10/20)
is this right?

Comment: No. https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp

Comment: I dont know after looking document, please make example December 25, 2022

Comment: I'd suggest to convert it to a string as indicated in the answer.